# Implementing topology rule Line Feature Class should not overlap with Polygon Feature Class in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, topology

Is there a way to setup such a rule in ArcMap 10 Topology that Line Feature Class features shouldn't overlap with Polygon Feature Class features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking about [map topology](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01mm0000000r000000), which is available for working with shared geometry, then it does not support rules like the one you are after.

For that you would need [geodatabase topology](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01mm0000000m000000) rules, and an ArcEditor/Standard (or ArcInfo/Advanced) license to create it.

---

When I wrote the above four years ago I suspect that I was looking at the [`Must Be Covered By Boundary Of` and/or `Must Be Inside` rules](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-topology/geodatabase-topology-rules-and-topology-error-fixes.htm).  In any event, I recommend testing to see whether one/both work for you because I appear to have been going from the documentation and not testing.

Comment: I'm looking through the geodatabase topology rules [even the latest ones](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-topology/geodatabase-topology-rules-and-topology-error-fixes.htm)  you linked to and don't see a rule to implement this.  The two "Must Not Overlap With" rules only allow comparing lines to lines and polygons to polygons.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @shthed When I wrote that four years ago I suspect that I was looking at the `Must Be Covered By Boundary Of` and/or `Must Be Inside` rules from http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-topology/geodatabase-topology-rules-and-topology-error-fixes.htm  In any event I recommend testing to see because I am pretty sure that I was going from the documentation and not testing.